# "pg_dump: invalid option -- i" when migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I run `rake db:migrate` on my Rails project (3.2.22.2) I get `pg_dump: invalid option -- i`. Here's the full trace:

```
Celluloid 0.17.1.1 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
pg_dump: invalid option -- i
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
rake aborted!
Error dumping database
/Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bm43/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:429:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bm43/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:202:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bm43/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:196:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bm43/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bm43/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I notice that there's a [bugfix in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21931) pertaining to this issue. The bugfix seems not to have been applied to Rails versions < 4 since it's not a security fix, which makes sense.

What I don't understand is what I'm supposed to do now. If there's a fix for 3.2.x, I haven't been able to find it yet. I guess if there's no fix for 3.2.x, I guess that means I have to upgrade to Rails 4.x, which seems a bit drastic. I doubt that's really the only solution. And why did the issue only recently pop up out of nowhere?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unlikely there is a fix as it's not a security issue. Even if it was, I'm not sure they are patching 3.x anymore.

The problem is in the db:structure:dump task here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.22.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L428

Easiest thing is to copy that task (413 - 448) and put it into your own lib/tasks directory, wrap a `namespace db` around it, tweak the pg_dump command (remove -i) and your task should override the built in task.

Comment: Ah, so basically write my own version of `rake db:migrate` (by copying the Rails source) with the -i taken out?

Comment: For it to work I had to add `Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].clear` at the beginning AND change [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.22.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L447) to `Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].reenable`

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this issue as well with Rails `3.2.22`. It looks like this was [fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21931) in `4.2.5`, but for our situation, upgrading Rails was not very practical.

After considering some options, I ended up down the path of overriding the default rake task `db:structure:dump` which is getting called after `db:migrate`.

I created a file `tasks/database.rake` and hacked together bits and pieces from different `ActiveRecord` methods to create a new `db:structure:dump` task. Now this new task is called instead of the default when `db:migrate`, etc is executed.

```
Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].clear
namespace :db do
  namespace :structure do
    desc "Overriding the task db:structure:dump task to remove -i option from pg_dump to make postgres 9.5 compatible"
    task dump: [:environment, :load_config] do
      config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
      set_psql_env(config)
      filename =  File.join(Rails.root, "db", "structure.sql")
      database = config["database"]
      command = "pg_dump -s -x -O -f #{Shellwords.escape(filename)} #{Shellwords.escape(database)}"
      raise 'Error dumping database' unless Kernel.system(command)

      File.open(filename, "a") { |f| f << "SET search_path TO #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path};\n\n" }
      if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.supports_migrations?
        File.open(filename, "a") do |f|
          f.puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.dump_schema_information
          f.print "\n"
        end
      end
      Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].reenable
    end
  end

  def set_psql_env(configuration)
    ENV['PGHOST']     = configuration['host']          if configuration['host']
    ENV['PGPORT']     = configuration['port'].to_s     if configuration['port']
    ENV['PGPASSWORD'] = configuration['password'].to_s if configuration['password']
    ENV['PGUSER']     = configuration['username'].to_s if configuration['username']
  end
end
```

This code was created specifically for our project, so if you have any other custom configurations set like `db_dir`, you will need to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

This error because '-i' method depricated in 9.5.X and higher versions.
Bug fixed in Rails -v '4.2.5' and you can update your Rails to this version or upper.
But if you need fast method I think you'll satisfied with it (it's just hack, do not use it if you have little bit doubting or you don't agree with it!):

1) find this file:  'postgresql_database_tasks.rb' (in my case it was):

```
/Users/YourUserName/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb
```

2) Open it, find and edit line below with remove '-i' from string:

```
command = "pg_dump -s -x -O -f #{Shellwords.escape(filename)} #{search_path} #{Shellwords.escape(configuration['database'])}"
```

3) save this file and start your rake task again!
That it!

Comment: saved my time. if spring is running like mine, after the edit run `killall ruby` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently got this very error with Rails 4.2.1 after trying to run `rake db:migrate`.

I was able to overcome it by upgrading to Rails 4.2.6 and letting `bundle update` do it's job bumping all related gems.

Hope that becomes useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could edit your local `pg_dump` to remove the `-i` option. Although individual installs may differ, here are the edits I made:

The command iterates through all it's arguments (line 36):

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#ARGV; ++$i) {
```

Find the conditional (line 39):

```
if ($ARGV[$i] eq '--cluster') {
```

Add the following (line 57):

```
} elsif ($ARGV[$i] eq '-i') {
    splice @ARGV, $i, 1;
}
```

Comment: How did you do this? I checked mine, my postgre12's pg_dump is a binary file.

Comment: @SamuelDev Oh ok, my local pg_dump is not a binary, using Ubuntu 16. I'm sure local setups will vary.