# Rails 3.2 structure.sql changes not generating

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

On this particular project we're on Rails 3.2 and we use SQL for our schema format, which generates `structure.sql`. So in application.rb:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

This has never been an issue in the past. Whenever migrations are run, Rails would automatically update `structure.sql` accordingly.

However, recently this stopped happening. No matter what changes in the db structure, `structure.sql` will not update. Unable to get to the root of the issue I've recently been updating `structure.sql` manually; which is a horrible, error-laden ritual at best.

Any thoughts appreciated.

#### Update

After reading ["pg_dump: invalid option -- i" when migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999906/pg-dump-invalid-option-i-when-migrating) it seems like it may be related to a bug in Rails 3.2.x conflicting with postgresql 9.5+. So I'm not sure if there is a solution outside of upgrading Rails which isn't currently a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
rake db:structure:dump
```

Comment: Nothing is generated when I do that. As it happens, whenever I run a rake task of any kind I get the following error:

`pg_dump: invalid option -- i
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
rake aborted!
Error dumping database`

I'm not 100% sure if it's related, cause a few other developers have had this issue, but are still getting `structure.sql` files generated.

Comment: There you go, I rephrased my answer.