# Running db:migrate kills the schema file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time I run `rake db:migrate`, my schema file is always changed to this

```
# A bunch of comments up here
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: WHATEVER_MY_LATEST_VERSION_IS) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

end
```

It will update the schema version, and run the migration. The tables will be created, indexes are created. It just leaves my schema.rb with nothing but this `enable_extension` in it. Running `rake db:schema:dump`will create the same schema file. I'm running on rails `4.1.10`.

**EDIT** I do have the pg gem installed (0.18.1). There's no outstanding migrations. This app has been in production for over 2 years now. It's been doing this issue for the last year or so, but we only do a new migration maybe twice a year so we haven't put much effort in to it until now. My DB yml is pretty standard:

```
defaults: &defaults
  encoding: utf8
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost') %>
  min_messages: WARNING

development:
  <<: *defaults
```

Comment: Do you have a definition for the test database in `config/database.yml`? Edit: Also try turning off `min_messages: WARNING` since that could be silencing something important.

Comment: Does `rake db:structure:dump` work?

Comment: Hmm.. weird. When I run `rake db:structure:dump`, I get `pg_dump: invalid option -- i` and rake aborted. I did removed the `min_messages`. Also, I do have a test, staging, and production all defined. They're just not showing in my example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999906/pg-dump-invalid-option-i-when-migrating

Comment: and here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23030, interesting issue

Comment: Thanks. I did come across that github issue earlier. I've started on the path to upgrade. So that's going to take a while. I guess I just need to wait until I can get to a later version of rails to really test this issue. It may just be a case of it being an older version.

Comment: If you really need those schema dumps you could add the `sequel-rails` gem to your project and in application.rb set `config.sequel.load_database_tasks = :sequel` and then run `rake sequel:schema:dump` or `rake sequel:structure:dump`. Just an idea, I've used that myself.